# Simple observable/observer in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I've tried 2 different ways to setup an observer/observable to make this code work:

**Setup #1:**

```
var xObserver;
var xObservable = Rx.Observable
    .create(observer => xObserver = observer)
    .publish()
    .refCount();
```

**Setup #2:**

```
var xObserver = Rx.Subject.create();
var xObservable = x;
```

**Usage**

```
xObserver.next('foo'); // no subscription yet, so nothing should happen
xObservable.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // pipe values to console
xObserver.next('bar'); // push another value, should go to console
```

My expectation is for nothing to happen when "foo" is pushed to the observer, and for only "bar" to be shown on the console.

With "Setup #1" I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined" which makes sense because no observer has subscribed yet so the `xObserver` is not initialized yet.

With "Setup #2" I get an error "TypeError: xObserver.next is not a function".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
let xObs = new Rx.Subject();
```

When you use `.create` you have to supply an Observer, see the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable) for details.

---

Another pitfall might be the version, in version < 5 there is only `.onNext()`:

```
xObs.onNext("myData");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzkmuewf/

In version > 5, there is only `.next()`:

```
xObs.next("myData");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j1sksg7q/

Comment: Actually, this isn't working.  `subject.next` is undefined when I do this:
```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.next(123);
```

Comment: You don't happen to be using rxjs <= version 4.1? In that case it'd be `.onNext()` - since you wrote `.next` in your code, I was assuming that you are using >5.x.x

Comment: Looks like I am using 4.1.0 as that is the latest available on npm.  Strange that `.next` is working in other cases using this same version of `rxjs`.

Comment: does it work with `.onNext()` for you? - I've added two live-fiddle for both versions and everything works there.

Comment: Yep, `.onNext` works.  Now I'm going to open an issue on the github repo to ask why v5 isn't on npm.

Comment: v5 is `npm install rxjs`(it's a serparte github repository: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) - v4 is `npm install rx`